# Double sink with disposal - water shoots up when disposal runs

Tags: plumbing

[image]I have a double sink with a disposal on the right side.  The disposal joins the left sink drain via a slip joint baffle tee below the left sink then the drain goes to the P-trap and out.  It was installed by a licensed plumber.

Every time the disposal is turned on water shoots up into the left sink which is where we like to keep a dish drainer.  What can be done to stop the water from shooting up?

Comment: Your sink might be clogged. Also, consider adding photos of the underside of your sink.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/90311/42053 could be relevant.

Comment: Can you add a picture of what under the sink?

Comment: Do you have an "air gap" unit installed?

Comment: Is it too small a diameter waste?

Comment: 1 1/2 standard sink plumbing.  Sink is not clogged.  Both sinks drain fine.

Comment: A photo or sketch would really help. You may be able to easily reconfigure the compression fittings to resolve this, but it's hard to say without seeing what you have now. You could even grab an example that matches your scenario from [search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=double+sink+plumbing+with+disposal&rlz=1C1ZCEB_enUS850US850&sxsrf=ACYBGNTOUXyo8ALumt8GkCg6KFLm92BzMw:1576875614278&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiS5d-2j8XmAhWWXc0KHesvDYgQ_AUoAnoECA0QBA&biw=1841&bih=979).

Comment: I'm guessing [this one](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pYKXGDBxx_k/maxresdefault.jpg).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. You should [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: You have a 90 degree tee, there are “swept” tees available that will promote the flow downwards...

Answer (score 4):

My instincts are inline with the comments by MonkeyZues and Solar Mike. The impeller design of some disposals accelerates the discharge. A partially plugged trap will send water up, following the path of least resistance (and still let the sinks drain). If the discharge from the disposal swept down (with a swept tee) the discharge would be directed down instead of splashing into the vertical-side of the straight tee. Both ideas are simple and inexpensive - cleaning the trap and swapping the tee.

Comment: Not sure that this is the answer, but it sounds likely to me and will take less than $5 and roughly 30 minutes to find out.

Answer (score 2):

Baffled Tee.

[image]

*How to Install a Garbage Disposer* - [plumbingsupply.com](https://www.plumbingsupply.com/how-to-install-a-garbage-disposer.html)

Comment: Looks like this "baffled T" was designed for this issue. I didn't know they existed. Thanks Mazura!

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a dedicated p-trap for the garbage disposal, which would also cause the Tee to be slightly lower and further down from the sink, which might also help.  I have seen installation where there are separate P-traps for both.

It might also help to lower the tee to make it further from the sink.